# Is it possible to have an unordered_map with non-const key type?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map, stdmap

Essentially, I'd like a container in which one element can be accessed by many keys. This could be done by defining some multi-key class to be used as the map's key type, but since such a solution doesn't allow modification of the keys of elements which have already been inserted, I'm unable to make new aliases for existing entries.

I appreciate that with `std::map` keys need to be constant for the purposes of ordering, but why should this limitation exist with `std::unordered_map`?

If need be, I suppose I could just use a map of pointers, but is there a better, more elegant solution?

Edit: Thanks for clearing that up Andrei, Xeo. Nicol, any suggestions as to what container I should used?

Comment: The limitation is in place not for ordering but to guarantee uniqueness of the keys.

Comment: Because elements are ultimately checked for equivalence through the comparator template argument, `std::equal_to<K>` by default.

Comment: If you need this, then you need a new container.

Comment: don't quite understand what is "unable to make new aliases for existing entries". perhaps give an example of what you wanted to do?

Comment: Well, if you could arbitrarily change the value of the keys, the `unordered_map` would need to sense each and every change (so would have to work on some kind of proxy object of the key, anyway) in order to restructure itself, which would in turn invalidate any iterators to the element. The key determines an element's position in the data structure, so modifying it only brings troubles. And this doesn't even talk about violating the uniqueness of the keys by changing it.

Comment: This is _technically_ possible, but I don't understand why you need to do this?  If you need to look up values by multiple keys there are much better ways to accomplish this.  `shared_ptr` of your content, stored in several distinct containers (each with their own key), or look into http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Answer (score 8):

Well, the reason why `std::unordered_map` does not let you modify the key is pretty much the same as the reason why other associative containers won't let you modify it: it would mess up the internal organization of that data structure.

In an `unordered_map`, the key is used to obtain a hash, and that hash tells the container in which bucket to place your element (and which bucket to retrieve it from, of course). If you modify the key, you modify the hash, and that means your element should be moved to a different bucket. That's like removing it and inserting it again, basically.

The whole idea of an associative container, on the other hand, is that any element is represented by one value which is fixed, so that its position in the container can be quickly computed as a function of that value. If multiple keys were allowed, which one would you use to quickly determine where the element is stored or is to be stored?

What you want is probably an *ad-hoc* data structure with complexity guarantees different from the ones of the Standard Library.

Personally, however, it seems to me like you are just looking for *reference semantics*, because you intend to share several views of one object. That would naturally lead me to the use of (smart) pointers, especially when I hear the world "alias". I suggest you to go for a map with `shared_ptr`s as values.

Comment: It doesn't need to imply a `shared_ptr`. The problem with a `sahred_ptr` is that once using it you opt-in for dynamically allocating your objects. Maybe a master map with views into it might also do (ok, that comes with other problems, really depends what he needs). But +1 for the answer, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Well, technically you are right I guess. On the other hand, from the practical standpoint, if the OP wants to create aliases, he normally would not want to bother with manually guaranteeing that the objects outlive all of their references, so `shared_ptr`s are likely to come handy.

Answer (score 2):

In associative containers (e.g. `map`, `unordered_map`), the value of `key` determines the position of the element in the data structure. In the non-multi associative containers, it is also necessary that the keys are unique.

If modifying the `key` were allowed, then that would jeopardize the aforementioned design invariants.

- In `map`, placement of the element in the binary search tree
- In `unordered_map`, linking the element to a hash bucket

If I understand OP's requirement, then it might be achieved by writing a wrapper on the container's `insert()`, such as the following C++-ish pseudocode:

```
Iterator insert_wrapper( Container & cont, Element const & elem ) {

    if elem in cont {
       cont.erase( elem );
    }

    return cont.insert( elem );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you find a map of references more tasteful than a map of pointers?

```
int value = 6;

std::unordered_map<int, int&> m;

for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    m.emplace(i, value);

value = 4;

for(auto const& i: m)
    std::cout<<i.second<<' ';
```

Of course, you have to store the actual values somewhere else, as the example has shown.